# Border radius for Photoshop Pen Shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, shapes

When I draw some line shape using Pen tool and fill it, it has sharp borders. How can I apply border radius to them to make them look like this image?

[image]

I can see the border radius option in the rectangle tool but cannot find when using Pen tool.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the **Pen Tool** to make a shape, after making the line there are shape options at the top menu.

At the **Stroke Options**, choose **Caps:** rounded

[image: Top menu options]

[image: Rounded caps]

Comment: wow! exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot, especially for the gif :)

Answer (score 2):

The Pen tool is all manual and you can basicly draw anything, including rounded rectangles, but that's only manual drawing line by line. For this particular purpose there is the Rounded Rectangle tool.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that I can do it using Rounded Rectangle Tool but I want to draw a random line (like a wage), that's using pen tool.

Comment: Not. Possible. Talk to Adobe :)

Comment: ah ok, I'm new to Photoshop, I thought it could do all magic :)

Comment: Apparently there is something, see the other answer, though i'm not sure if that works with what you need.. try it out.